# Jenkins Groovy script to get timestamp of last triggered build in all jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

How can i limit below groovy script to pick only last triggered build? it is listing information for every build with original script.

I tried in many ways but observing compilation failures. can someone please help? My target is to get the timestamp of last triggered build for all the jobs in jenkins from all the folders.

https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/get-build-information.groovy

**I tried below code**

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job).each{

  build ->
  def runningSince = groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus( new Date(), build.getTime() )
  def currentStatus = build.buildStatusSummary.message
  def cause = build.getCauses()[0] //we keep the first cause
  //This is a simple case where we want to get information on the cause if the build was 
  //triggered by an user
  def user = cause instanceof Cause.UserIdCause? cause.getUserId():""
  //This is an easy way to show the information on screen but can be changed at convenience
  println "Build: ${build} | Since: ${runningSince} | Status: ${currentStatus} " 
       }
```

**Error log:**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.getTime() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getName(), getScm(), getSCMs(), getACL(), getApi(), getUrl()
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:4)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2056)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4042)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4014)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1257.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:324)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:167)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:100)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.ha.HAHealthCheckFilter.doFilter(HAHealthCheckFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:249)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.support.slowrequest.SlowRequestFilter.doFilter(SlowRequestFilter.java:38)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.requestfilter.BlockingFilter.doFilter(BlockingFilter.java:36)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at com.cloudbees.opscenter.client.plugin.OfflineSecurityRealmFilter._doFilter(OfflineSecurityRealmFilter.java:90)
at com.cloudbees.opscenter.client.plugin.OfflineSecurityRealmFilter.doFilter(OfflineSecurityRealmFilter.java:67)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at com.cloudbees.opscenter.security.ClusterSessionFilter._doFilter(ClusterSessionFilter.java:69)
at com.cloudbees.opscenter.security.ClusterSessionFilter.doFilter(ClusterSessionFilter.java:44)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.suppress_stack_trace.SuppressionFilter.doFilter(SuppressionFilter.java:34)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:85)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:102)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:95)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you share the compilation error you are getting?

Comment: Hi mbn217, Edited the post with the code i tried and copied the error logs